# Button Visibility bound to SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, visibility

I'm having a little problem with Binding. I want to bind 2 buttons with the `SelectedItem` of a `ListBox`.

The `ListBox` contains several values and displays them (Name, Age,...). When the user selects one entry of the `ListBox`, the 2 buttons "Delete" and "Change" should popup (<- be visible), so this means the buttons-visibility should be bound with the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` and are next to the ListBox-Item (like the "Delete"-Button of iPhone).

My code actually makes the buttons visible when I select an item, BUT the problem is that ALL BUTTONS of ALL ITEMS are being visible!
The actual code (which needs to be fixed) is this (the Visibility part):

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Content="Delete" Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=lbuser, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Delete}"/>
<Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Content="Change" Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=lbuser, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Change}" />
```

But if someone needs the full code, here it is:

```
<Grid Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="212"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="lbuser" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedListView, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="390" Width="Auto" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Bezeichnung}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FontSize="22.5" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Name"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Age"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=Age, Converter={StaticResource EuroConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="E-Mail"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=EMail}" Width="Auto"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Phone"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=Phone, Converter={StaticResource EuroConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Born"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=YearBorn}" Width="Auto"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Birthplace"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=Birthplace}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Content="Delete" Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=lbuser, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Delete}"/>
                    <Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Content="Change" Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=lbuser, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Change}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Edit: VisibilityConverter

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region [ IValueConverter ]

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

the value is the selecteditem, which means when the ListBox has 2 Items and I click on one Item, the VisibilityConverter will be called 4 times and set the Visibility to true. By the 4 callings of the converter, the value is always the SelectedItem.

Comment: What does the VisibilityConverter do? The Visibilityconverter must be able to handle the type of SelectedItem. Did you tried to set a breakpoint in your implementation of the VisibilityConverter?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the visibility to `MySelectedListView`. That is the ViewModels property the selected item of the listbox is bound to. Then the value should be of the correct type.

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Content="Delete" Visibility="{Binding Path=MySelectedListView, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Delete}"/>
```

You should be able to omit `DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}"` if you have not set the datacontext on a higher level.

**Edit:** Another option would be to bind to a ButtonVisibility property in the `User` view model class. In the MySelcetedListView setter set the value of the existing object to `Collapsed` or `Hidden` (whatever fits your need) and that of the new one to `Visible`. Binding would then be `Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility}"`

Comment: I've set the DataContext in another ViewModel (don't ask why... :P), so I need this entry. Binding to _MySelectedListView_ doesn't work, it shows the same result. The property in the ViewModel looks like this: `public User MySelectedListView`